# Apply constraint to equation, Wolfram Alpha.

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I think it's being able to handle gracefully this one:

```
a * -2 + b * 5 = -9
```

Yields me several interpretations, one of them I like:

```
a = 5n + 2, b = 2n - 1, n ∊ ℤ
```

Now because `a` and `b` are Stack Exchange downvotes and upvotes on questions; and if I fed a `0` to the solution it handed me, it would yield `a = 2, b = -1` where `b` fails to be in ℕ; I tried to apply an additional constraint to it:

```
a * -2 + b * 5 = -9 such that a > -1 and b > -1
```

But I'm unable to find such interpretation in the answers it's proposing me.

How to / What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can examine your solution and determine that $n\ge 1$ will force both constraints to be satisfied.

Comment: But then I would want to enter `a * -2 + b * 5 = -9 such that n > 0` instead of `a * -2 + b * 5 = -9 such that a > -1 and b > -1` and my material issue with using the tool prevails.

Comment: In Mathematica (which is generally superior to W|A in these situations), you can probably use the `Assumptions->{a>-1, b>-1}` command. That might even work in W|A, but it's not guaranteed. But my point above is that you don't actually need that in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
a * -2 + b * 5 = -9, a > -1, b > -1
```

did what I wanted. At first I thought it was interpreting a tuple, but I finally found

```
a = 5n + 2, b = 2n - 1, n ∊ ℤ, n ≥ 1
```

as the last interpretation.